# How to echo values from multidimensional array which is in key value pair using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array which contain values from database table but values are key value format so i tried to print using forloop and foreach loop but unable to get output ,so how to do this using php forloop or foreach loop?

Values from array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Email] => xyz@gmail.com
                    [mobile] => 123456
                    [address] => 'xyz xyz'
                    [maritalstatus] => 'married'

                    [Role] => 'employee'

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [joiningdate] => 2012-11-01
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Email] => abc@gmail.com
                    [mobile] => 123456
                    [address] => 'xyz xyz'

                    [maritalstatus] => 'married'
                    [Role] => 'employee'


                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [joiningdate] => 2012-11-01
                )

        )

        )
```

print values using forloop

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($rows); $x++) {

                            echo '<tr>';
                            foreach ($rows[$x][0] as $key => $value) {

                                $indexposition = array_search($key, array_keys($rows[$x][0]));


                            }
                            echo '</tr>';
                            }
```

Comment: try `foreach ($x as $key => $value) {
foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
echo $val['Email'];
}
}`

Comment: What is your expected output? Please add it to your question.

Comment: @d.coder my expected output is to print all values with ots key value pair

Comment: if all of your arrays are like the array so the @guradio comment is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just print the array use var_dump($your_variable) other wise say what exactly you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally  got solution by simple way. 
Suppose we are getting all this array from $rows then

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($rows); $x++) {

$mergearray = array_merge($rows[$x][0], $rows[$x][1]);

  foreach ($mergearray as $key => $value) {

//Here echo  your values i. $value;
}

}
```